# Extracting a value in python with specific JSON array

Tags: python, json

New to python how would I get the value out of the key value pair appid in the below JSON?

```
  {
   "Datadog":[
      "host:i-068fee2324438213477be9a4"
   ],
   "Amazon Web Services":[
      "availability-zone:us-east-1a",
      "aws:cloudformation:logical-id:ec2instance01",
      "aws:cloudformation:stack-id:arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:353245",
      "appid:42928482474dh28424a",
      "name:devinstance",
      "region:us-east-1",
      "security-group:sg-022442414d8a",
      "security-group:sg-0691af18875ad9d0b",
      "security-group:sg-022442414d8a",
      "security-group:sg-022442414d8a"
   ]
}
```

Comment: What you have is NOT JSON (note `'` rather than `"`)

Answer (score 0):

What you're using is a dictionnary. You can access the values like this

`nameOfYourDict["nameOfYourKey"]`

For example if the name of your dict is data and you want to access Datadog :

`data["Datadog"]`

Comment: i think the issue here is that the key value looks like a dict (or json if you want) but its a string inside the inner list, so it might look more like: ׳dict_name["Amazon Web Services"][3]׳

Answer (score 0):

Start by getting the AWS pairs into their own variable:

```
aws_pairs = data["Amazon Web Services"]
```

Then loop over the pairs until you find one with the correct anchor:

```
appid_pair = None
for pair in aws_pairs:
    if pair.startswith("appid:"):
        appid_pair = pair
        break

appid_value = None
if appid_pair:
    appid_value = appid_pair.split(":", 1)[1]

print(appid_value)
```

Breaking this down into a simple next statement:

```
aws_pairs = data["Amazon Web Services"]
appid_value = next(
    (
        pair.split(":", 1)[1]
        for pair in aws_pairs 
        if pair.startswith("appid:")
    ),
    None
)

print(appid_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a JSON thing, you have a dictionary of lists so extract the relevant list then search it for the item you're looking for:

```
x = {
   "Datadog":[
      "host:i-068fee2324438213477be9a4"
   ],
   "Amazon Web Services":[
      "availability-zone:us-east-1a",
      "aws:cloudformation:logical-id:ec2instance01",
      "aws:cloudformation:stack-id:arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:353245",
      "appid:42928482474dh28424a",
      "name:devinstance",
      "region:us-east-1",
      "security-group:sg-022442414d8a",
      "security-group:sg-0691af18875ad9d0b",
      "security-group:sg-022442414d8a",
      "security-group:sg-022442414d8a"
   ]
}

aws = x["Amazon Web Services"]
for string in aws:
    name, value = string.split(":", 1)
    if name == "appid":
        print(value)
```

Gives:

```
42928482474dh28424a
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient approach I can think of is to check if each tag (under the "Amazon Web Services" key) starts with a specified prefix, or tag name in this case.

Note that you can also use `str.startswith`, however here I just use a substring lookup, which also has the same effect.

```py
data = {
   "Datadog": [
      "host:i-068fee2324438213477be9a4"
   ],
   "Amazon Web Services": [
      "availability-zone:us-east-1a",
      "aws:cloudformation:logical-id:ec2instance01",
      "aws:cloudformation:stack-id:arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:353245",
      "appid:42928482474dh28424a",
      "name:devinstance",
      "region:us-east-1",
      "security-group:sg-022442414d8a",
      "security-group:sg-0691af18875ad9d0b",
      "security-group:sg-022442414d8a",
      "security-group:sg-022442414d8a"
   ]
}['Amazon Web Services']

target_tag = 'appid:'
len_tag_name = len(target_tag)

for tag in data:
    if tag[:len_tag_name] == target_tag:
        app_id = tag[len_tag_name:]
        break
else:  # no `break` statement encountered, hence app_id not found
    app_id = None

assert app_id == '42928482474dh28424a'  # True
```

And finally, here is a one-liner version of the above, using a `next` iterator to find the first match in a generator expression. This should work if you know for sure that an `appid` tag exists.

```
app_id = next(tag[len_tag_name:] for tag in data if tag[:len_tag_name] == target_tag)
```